# Android: scrollable image gallery layout

Tags: android, image, gallery

I would like to have a scrollable image gallery that takes up most of the screen. My images are small icons all of the same size. I can have a lot of images. Once the maximum number of images fills the screen horizontally, they should wrap to the next row. If there are more images than will fit in the vertical direction, then it should be possible to scroll vertically to view additional images. I am not sure what layout controls I should be using to accomplish this. An additional feature (be not a must have), is that the images are equally spaced horizontally with the same amount of margin. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Completely forgot about the GridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use `GridView`. Perfectly fits your needs.